# Load multiple URLs in WebView one by one

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I am trying to load multiple URLs on a `WebView` named `browser` on `MainActivity` using a separate class `Searcher`.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.myuser.hplap.myapp.MainActivity.browser;

public class Searcher {
    static List<String> keywords;

    Searcher() {
        populate();
        search();
    }

    void populate() {
        keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
        keywords.add("how to cook rice");
        keywords.add("how to sing");
        keywords.add("how to dance");
    }

    void search() {
        for (String kw : keywords)
            browser.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" + "buy+" + kw.replace(' ', '+'));
    }
}
```

I plan to simply call this class' constructor and let everything be done automatically.

But the loop runs too fast therefore `browser` is only able to load the last URL.

I am only going to copy the HTML code of the loaded webpages onto a String in the `MainActivity` so I don't need to keep the page loaded for much time.

Here's the code for MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static String code;
    static WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            /* An instance of this class will be registered as a JavaScriptInterface interface */
            class MyJavaScriptInterface {
                @JavascriptInterface
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public void processHTML(String html) {
                    code = html;

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            count.setText(String.valueOf(totalProducts));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");

            browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    browser.loadUrl("javascript:HTMLOUT.processHTML(document.documentElement.outerHTML);");
                }
            });

            /* load a web page */
            new Searcher();
        }

}
```

I was hoping if someone could help me out here.
Thank you for reading so far :)

Comment: @VladMatvienko the solution worked, thanks :)

Comment: can you provide the worked code ? you can edit your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load next page after calling `onPageFinished` only. So I'd say your `Searcher` needs one more method like `loadNext()`, which will load next page after this one has been loaded